# DOMXPath - Select only a few items

Tags: domxpath

Let's say we have this html and the following DOMXPath code:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>6</p>
    </div>
</div>

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($strhtml);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );

$nodelist = $xpath->query('//div/div[2]/p');

foreach( $nodelist as $node ) {
    $result = $node->nodeValue."\n";
}

echo $result;
```

Obviously, `$result = '2'`, since we asked for the value of 'p' from the second 'div' node.

Now, how can I get the values for, say, from '`div[2]`' to '`div[4]`' and sum them?

To be precise, I would like to know how to get **"from # to #"** and also how to get **"this #, that #, also # and #"**. So two questions, for two different problems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to select range of elements with `DOMXPath`:

- as for the first problem  ***to get "from # to #"*** use the
  following approach:

  ```
  // select nodes within specified range of positions
  $nodelist = $xpath->query('//div/div[position()>1 and position()<5]');
  ```
- as for the second problem **to get "this #, that #, also # and #"**
  try the following (with `|` union operator):

  ```
  // extracts the 2nd, 4th and 6th elements respectively
  $nodelist = $xpath->query('//div/div[2] | //div/div[4] | //div/div[6]);
  ```